# JSON schema - conditionally apply a $ref to a value based on the other value?

Tags: jsonschema

I am wanting to conditionally validate against a $ref based on another value in my schema.

```
items: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      kind: { type: 'string', enum: ['foo', 'bar'] },
      //parameters: { $ref: 'foo.json#' } // This works
      parameters: {
        if: {
          kind: 'foo'
        },
        then: {
          $ref: 'foo.json#'
        }
      }
      // also tried   
      if: {
        kind: 'foo'
      },
      then: {
        parameters: { $ref: 'foo.json#' }
      }
```

I would like `parameters` to be validated against the `foo.json` reference whenever the value of `kind` is equal to `foo` (same with `bar` and `bar.json`). However the above is not working. Uncommenting out the commented section works so they are not equivalent.

How can I format this to conditionally apply a $ref to a value based on the other value?

I actually have about 10 different values for the `type` enum so if there is a cleaner way do this than if/else I am open.

Answer (score 1):

Ah got it....

```
items: {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    kind: { type: 'string', enum: ['foo', 'bar'] }
  },
  required: ['parameters'],
  if: {
    properties: { kind: { const: 'foo' } },
    required: ['kind']
  },
  then: {
    properties: {
      parameters: {
        $ref: 'fpp.json#'
      }
    }
  }
```

It's helpful for me to think that whatever is in `if` and `else` are essentially merged with the main schema.